# Is there official documentation for python's len() function warning that it can sometimes return apparently wrong values for some strings?

Tags: python

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for name in ["Blue Oyster Cult", "Blue Öyster Cult", "Spinal Tap", "Spın̈al Tap"]:
...     print(f'{len(name):3d} {name}')
... 
 16 Blue Oyster Cult
 16 Blue Öyster Cult
 10 Spinal Tap
 11 Spın̈al Tap
>>> quit()
```

I'm not asking for an explanation of this behaviour, I'm asking for any official documentation for the `len()` function itself saying that it will return a seemingly wrong answer for the last case.

Comment: `Ö` is one Unicode character. `n̈` is two. There's nothing wrong with `len`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi says "*There's nothing wrong with len*".  I didn't' say there was. I said "seemingly wrong".  What I want to know is how I could have known that this would be the result based on the documentation of the len() function.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi `Ö` can also consist of 2 unicode characters.

Comment: Don't blame `len` for what `str.__len__` does.

Comment: @jsiller sure, but in this case it is one.

Comment: @RayButterworth the Python documentation from a Unicode or Internationalisation perspective is suboptimal. It is more a question of understanding the Unicode specification and experience, rather than finding the answer in the Python documentation. Have a look at the glossary at the Unicode site: look at the entries for Character, Code point, Grapheme, Unicode String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

len() returns the length of a sequence:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len

A string is defined as a sequence of Unicode code points:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str

So by knowing what a Unicode code point is, and of how many this particular string consists, you could have known what len() returns.

The documentation does not explicitly warn you that a string can have a different number of Unicode code points than what you expect.

However, there is a "Unicode HOWTO" that explains a bit more about code points:

https://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: The string consists of a sequence of characters. The key distinction, for this question, is the difference between characters that make up the string, and extended grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that need to be distinguished. The first is the number of characters in a string. This is given by `len()`.

```
s = "n̈"
print(len(s))
# 2
```

Which makes sense because n̈ is U+006E U+0308, the letter n, followed by a combining diaeresis.

The second is what is referred to as user-perceived letters (in technical parlance extended grapheme clusters).

```
import regex as re
def graphemes(text):
    return re.findall(r'\X',text)
print(len(graphemes(s)))
# 1
```

So n̈ is two characters, but one grapheme.

Emojis, can be more complex:

```
e = "‍‍"
len(e)                     # 5
print(len(graphemes(e)))   # 1
```

One emoji created by five Unicode characters.

The length of a string is fluid, different text transformations can change the length of a string. Uppercasing or lowercasing strings can change the length of a string. Casefolding can change the length. Title casing can change the length. Unicode normalisation can change the length.

Answer (score 0):

The length is not wrong the `n̈` is just stored as 2 [code points](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), specifically the numerical values 110 and 776.
You can convert a string to its numerical representation like this:

```py
>>> [ord(c) for c in "Spın̈al Tap"]
[83, 112, 305, 110, 776, 97, 108, 32, 84, 97, 112]
```

If you convert it to a list of characters like this:

```py
>>> [c for c in "Spın̈al Tap"]
['S', 'p', 'ı', 'n', '̈', 'a', 'l', ' ', 'T', 'a', 'p']
```

as you can see the `n̈` glyph consists of the characters `n` and `'̈'`

Comment: The "Ö" is also multi-byte unicode, and len() handles that one as expected. But I'm not asking why it behaves this way, I'm asking if there's anything in the definition of len() that indicates that this is what will happen.,

Comment: No `Ö` can consist of one or two characters. You are probably using the one which only uses one character.

Comment: Your answer says "two bytes".  It should say "two characters".

Comment: Given that a byte can only store values up to 255, any integer value you see in there that is > 255 is "stored as two bytes".